# Remove gap between button border and background image

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to implement some navigation buttons (no text, only image, like flat button).

I add default button with BackgroundImage property. And it has a small gap between border and image.

How can I remove that gap?

Comment: Set FlatStyle to Flat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far i got your concern.
You need to set two properties of Button.

1. `button.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;`
2. `button1.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Set border property to None will make the button fully flat and just flat image will be shown

Answer (score 0):

Set FlatStyle to Flat

```
button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
```